# NLP Code Snippets NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp, chatbot

I'm writing an application in NodeJS with the [talkify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/talkify) library.  The point of the application is to be a chatbot.  Part of the functionality of the bot will be to take code (a closed source language) snippets, process them via a REST API, and return the result.

I've been able to create some trivial skills with talkify and it works fine.  My main question is how would I implement my bot to interpret code snippets between single quotes in a given skill?

I'm not tied to talkify by any means.  If someone has a suggestion that's better suited for my use case then I'm open to changing.

Code I have so far

```
// Core dependency
const talkify = require('talkify');
const Bot = talkify.Bot;

// Types dependencies
const BotTypes = talkify.BotTypes;
const Message = BotTypes.Message;
const SingleLineMessage = BotTypes.SingleLineMessage;
const MultiLineMessage = BotTypes.MultiLineMessage;

// Skills dependencies
const Skill = BotTypes.Skill;

// Training dependencies
const TrainingDocument = BotTypes.TrainingDocument;

const bot = new Bot();

bot.trainAll([
    new TrainingDocument('how_many_endpoints', 'How many endpoints are there?'),
    new TrainingDocument('how_many_endpoints', 'How many endpoints are there')
], function() {});

var howManyAction = function(context, request, response, next) {
    response.message = new SingleLineMessage(function() {
      var x = someWork();
      return x;
});
    next();
};

var howSkill = new Skill('how_skill', 'how_are_you', howAction);
bot.addSkill(howSkill);

var resolved = function(err, messages) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);

    return console.log(messages);
};

bot.resolve(123, TEXT_FROM_CHAT, resolved);
```

The above works when I ask how many endpoints I want but it won't work for more complex sentences, for example, I might want to say

"execute the following 'this is closed source stuff, I'll parse it server side'"

How would I match "execute the following" to a rule and get the string inside the single quotes as another variable?  As I understand it the talkify library training documents must match the text it's parsing.

Example

Training document

```
execute the following
```

Text to match

```
execute the following <~ Match
execute the following 'foo bar' <~ No match
execute the following,   <~ No match
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-process the text to extract & remove any quoted phrase using a simple regex:

`/\'[^\']*\'/g`

See it running here: https://regex101.com/r/eUe7n3/1

hope it helps.